# Comparing only the selected value in loop to avoid error message

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a basic quiz system.The following code shows how  user choose the answer using radio butto and the getresult.php compares the radio input value with answer column. In my database there is a question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, and answer columns.

```
<form method="POST" action="getresult.php">
   <label>Enter Your Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text"  name="name"><br><br>
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM quiz");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    echo "<form method='POST' action='getresult.php'>";

    while($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

echo $myrow['id'];
echo ".";   
echo $myrow['question'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$myrow['id']."]' value=".$myrow['opt1'].">";
echo $myrow['opt1'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$myrow['id']."]' value=".$myrow['opt2'].">";
echo $myrow['opt2'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$myrow['id']."]' value=".$myrow['opt3'].">";
echo $myrow['opt3'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$myrow['id']."]' value=".$myrow['opt4'].">";
echo $myrow['opt4'];
echo "<br><br>";


}?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Results" class="btn btn-primary">
```

//    getresult.php

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM quiz");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();

$submit=isset($_POST['submit']);   
$count=0;

if($submit)
{
    while($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

        if($mycheck[$myrow['id']]==$myrow['answer'])
        {   
            $count=$count+1;
        }
}

    echo "Hello ";
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "You scored ";
    echo "$count";
}
```

Everything is correct, but if I do not select a radio button from a question, i.e if I leave the question it displays undefined offset error which is obvious but how can I not display that. OR how can I compare only chosen options?

Comment: I have tested your code and it works as expected. The only thing I can not reproduce is your database. Have you special characters in database fields? Side note 1: your HTML is not valid: you open `<form>` two times. Side note 2: **NEVER** use `extract()` on `$_GET`/`$_POST` ! It is totally unsafe.

Comment: @fusion3k i fixed the side notes. checked all the database fields. but still not found the solution.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running on?

Comment: Am I right and there are two form opening tags?

Comment: Using `extract($_POST);` may save you a few lines of code, but it's basically telling the internet "Please inject anything you like into my global namespace!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) like this:

```
    if(array_key_exists($myrow['id'], $mycheck)
        && array_key_exists('answer', $myrow)
        && $mycheck[$myrow['id']]==$myrow['answer'])
    {   
        $count=$count+1;
    }
```

Or better yet, request your answers from database based on validated rows.

Answer (score 2):

When the form is submitted, the chosen values are passed as (for example):

```
mycheck[1]=2
mycheck[2]=3
mycheck[3]=1
mycheck[4]=2
```

...etc. Now if you leave one question unanswered, let's say question 2, then no value will be submitted to the server for that question, so the submitted values could be something like this:

```
mycheck[1]=2
mycheck[3]=1
mycheck[4]=2
```

When PHP stores this in *$_POST[]*, it will be an associative array:

```
$_POST['mycheck'] === array(
    '1' => 2,
    '3' => 1,
    '4' => 2
)
```

With `extract($_POST)` you get the following value for *$mycheck*:

```
$mycheck === array(
    '1' => 2,
    '3' => 1,
    '4' => 2
)
```

Now the following loop in your code will still go through all questions:

```
while($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if($mycheck[$myrow['id']]==$myrow['answer'])
    {   
        $count=$count+1;
    }
}
```

But (in the example) the check for question 2 will fail, because *$myrow['id']* will equal 2, while *$mycheck[2]* does not exist. This produces the *undefined offset* error.

As an unanswered question obviously should not increase the count, you could solve this issue as follows: first test if the question was answered (does *$mycheck* have an entry for it?), and only if that is the case, retrieve the answer from that entry:

```
while($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $id = myrow['id'];
    if(array_key_exists($id, $mycheck) && $mycheck[$id]==$myrow['answer'])
    {
        $count=$count+1;
    }
}
```

For the above extra test you can use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), or [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Answer (score 0):

A bit rusted on PHP, but ...
Have you tried using the `isset()` function? Or changing the error reporting level appropriately?

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you create a new radio button "Don't know " which would be initially checked

```
<input type="radio" name="" checked>
```

So by default that button will be checked.

Comment: value would still be undefined server-side, this wouldn't help

Comment: I have created a online test script for one of my client and that trick helped me. Can you explain me the error

Comment: quoting OP "if I do not select a radio button from a question, i.e if I leave the question it displays undefined offset error"; your solution would add a new default option with no value, wich would make no difference on the "compare only chosen option" part.

Comment: consider db structure as [ques][option1][option2][option3][option4][correct ans]. Correct ans would store option no that is correct like 1,2,3,4 . If a user submits a answer, then compare the selected value with [correct ans] if it is correct increment the marks variable. If the user won't select any answer and submit then selected option would be 5 which will never be equal to value of[correct answer].

Comment: why not use isset() to check if any value is selected.

Comment: yes, that would help solve the problem; you should edit your answer accordingly to try to raise it's score